# PHP: многопользовательский remote debug через браузер

Tags: php, nginx, отладка, php-fpm, xdebug

**Вопрос:**

как сделать возможным удалённый дебаг для нескольких разработчиков одновременно при отправке запроса через браузер (при некоторых ограничениях)

**Дано:**

1) Сервер с закрытыми портами и возможностью подсоединения только по ssh

2) На сервере: Nginx, php7.1.8, php-fpm, xDebug 2.5.5

**Что я делаю для однопользовательского дебага:**

1) Создаю тунель

```
ssh -p 2222 -N -R 9001:127.0.0.1:9001 user@server.com
```

2) На сервере настраиваю xDebug следующим конфигом:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

3) В IDE указываю интерпритатор, маппинг директорий, какой порт слушать (в нашем случае `9001`)

4) В Chrome ставлю расширение для дебага.

---

**Предполагаю**, что если бы не тунель, то можно было бы разрулить всё настройкой расширения и фильтра в IDE

```
id session = PHPSTORM_{идентификатор разработчика}
```

и поиграться с параметром

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

Но пока ничего не получилось, подскажите, пожалуйста, какой есть выход? Можно ли как-то повлиять на `xdebug.remote_port=9001` и устанавливать это значение своё для каждого разработчика?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу удалось решить посредством **Nginx**

Что можно сделать для многопользовательского дебага:

1) Каждому разработчику назначается свой порт для дебага (9001, 9002, 9003  и т.д.)

2) Каждый разработчик создаёт для себя тунель (где `XXXX` - порт разработчика)

```
ssh -p 2222 -N -R XXXX:127.0.0.1:9000 user@server.com
```

3) Разработчик настраивает IDE слушать `9000` порт

4) На сервер xDebug со следующей конфигурацией:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
```

5) В Chrome все разработчики выставляют `session_id = PHPSTORM`

6) **И теперь самое главное, конфиг NGINX**

6.1) Каждому пользователю назначаем свой хост, пример:

```
ivan.server.com
andrey.server.com
mihail.server.com
```

6.2) И для каждого хоста определяем свой порт для дебага (где `XXXX` - личный порт разработчика):

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  xdebug.remote_port=XXXX;
```